How to give the user account proper rights to premission for /run/seatd.sock?
I'm going to start weston in a user service. Starting weston in a super user service is no problem.
But when I'm starting weston by the regular user, the weston won't start due to this file
Could not connect to socket /run/seatd.sock. Premission denied

But if I do a trick
sudo chmod 777 /run/seatd.sock

Then my user service can start weston. But this is not a proper solution.
My question here is to give the user the proper rights to access /run/seatd.sock without using root.
How can I achieve that?
I have tried to check what rights the /runt/seatd.sock file have
ls -l /run/seatd.sock

And it gave me
srwxrwx--- 1 root video 0 aug 8 14:53 /run/seatd.sock

So I have tried with
sudo usermod -aG video user
su - user

Then checked
groups user | grep video
>> user : user video

But still, I don't have user access to the file /run/seatd.sock. So what should I do?

You could have added a supplementary group with sudo adduser $USER video, but then ...
Ensure $USER logs off (all the way off), and logs in again. Supplementary groups are set up as part of the login process.

How can I ensure that my user logs are off?

Ok. Now i understand what you mean with logs off. But this is the same as usermod -aG video user
